# 404 Not Found when getting Tracks from Spotify's Discover Weekly Playlist

Tags: php, spotify

I am trying to retrieve all tracks from my discover weekly playlist.

Although I granted every available scope and made the playlist public, both WEB API Console and Spotify Web PHP API get a 404 error response.

The strange thing is, that I can access all other private playlists, except the ones who are generated by Spotify. I can't access playlists from the users spotifydiscover, spotify_germany, spotlight_germany.

So therefore I think that Spotify forbids the access to these playlists? 
Or am I missing something?

Big thanks in advance for your help!

greetings,
jules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discover Weekly lists are owned by the "spotify" account, so you need to supply `spotify` as the Owner ID instead of your actual username. Then authenticate as your user, and the system will resolve the call properly. I verified that this works for mine.

Comment: Thank you very much, glenn! This works! I appreciate your help!